# How to start a new activity for separate components (parts) of listview items in Android

Tags: android

I have made a  `ListView` for my android app, and I have a problem creating separate `onClickListeners` for separate parts of the item. My item has a image1,image2 and a text. What I want is to start different activities depending on which of those has been clicked. Below is my code.

```
 **MainActivity.java**
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView mListView;
    ImageView rightarrow;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
       // URL to the JSON data         
        String strUrl = "url of php file";

        // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download json data 
        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

        // Starting the download process
        downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
    }


  /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url 
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
                iStream.close();
        }

        return data;
    }





/** AsyncTask to download json data */
        private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
            String data = null;
                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
                            try{
                                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);

                            }catch(Exception e){
                                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
                            }
                            return data;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                            // The parsing of the xml data is done in a non-ui thread 
                            ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();

                            // Start parsing xml data
                            listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);                        

                    }
        }



/** AsyncTask to parse json data and load ListView */
        private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter>{

            JSONObject jObject;
            // Doing the parsing of xml data in a non-ui thread 
            @Override
            protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
                try{
                    jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
                    CountryJSONParser countryJsonParser = new CountryJSONParser();
                    countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("JSON Exception1",e.toString());
                }

                // Instantiating json parser class
                CountryJSONParser countryJsonParser = new CountryJSONParser();

                // A list object to store the parsed countries list
                List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries = null;

                try{
                    // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                    countries = countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
                }          

                // Keys used in Hashmap 
              //  String[] from = { "country","flag","details"};
                String[] from = {"flag"};
                // Ids of views in listview_layout
               // int[] to = { R.id.tv_country,R.id.iv_flag,R.id.tv_country_details};
                int[] to = { R.id.iv_flag};

                // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
                // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item         
                SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), countries, R.layout.lv_layout, from, to);  

                return adapter;
            }

            /** Invoked by the Android on "doInBackground" is executed */
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {

                // Setting adapter for the listview
                mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
                    HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
                    String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("flag_path");
                    ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();

                    HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    hm.put("flag_path",imgUrl);
                    hm.put("position", i);

                    // Starting ImageLoaderTask to download and populate image in the listview 
                    imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);

                     }
            }

        }



/** AsyncTask to download and load an image in ListView */
        private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{

            @Override
            protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

                InputStream iStream=null;
                String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("flag_path");
                int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

                URL url;
                try {
                    url = new URL(imgUrl);

                    // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    // Connecting to url                
                    urlConnection.connect();

                    // Reading data from url 
                    iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                    // Getting Caching directory 
                    File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

                    // Temporary file to store the downloaded image 
                    File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+position+".png");



                  //  tmpFile.getParentFile().mkdirs(); 
                   // tmpFile.createNewFile(); 
                    // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                    FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                    // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
                    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);             

                    // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);              

                    // Flush the FileOutputStream
                    fOutStream.flush();

                    //Close the FileOutputStream
                    fOutStream.close();             

                    // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position in the listview
                    HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                    // Storing the path to the temporary image file
                    hmBitmap.put("flag",tmpFile.getPath());

                    // Storing the position of the image in the listview
                    hmBitmap.put("position",position);              

                    // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and position
                    return hmBitmap;                


                }catch (Exception e) {              
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
                // Getting the path to the downloaded image
                String path = (String) result.get("flag");          

                // Getting the position of the downloaded image
                int position = (Integer) result.get("position");

                // Getting adapter of the listview
                SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter ) mListView.getAdapter();

                // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the listview
                HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);   

                // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter 
                hm.put("flag",path);

                // Noticing listview about the dataset changes
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

            return true;
        }
    }
```

i am getting my `ListView` content from database.because `ListView` is a parent view so when i apply clicklistener on list view it get applied on each its item components. so i want `ListView` row and its components start different activities. 
HERE IS MY ADAPTER CLASS:

```
 public class CountryJSONParser {

// Receives a JSONObject and returns a list
public List<HashMap<String,Object>> parse(JSONObject jObject){      

    JSONArray jCountries = null;
    try {       
        // Retrieves all the elements in the 'countries' array 
        jCountries = jObject.getJSONArray("countries");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     // Invoking getCountries with the array of json object
     // where each json object represent a country
    return getCountries(jCountries);
}


private List<HashMap<String, Object>> getCountries(JSONArray jCountries){
    int countryCount = jCountries.length();
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> countryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> country = null; 

    // Taking each country, parses and adds to list object 
    for(int i=0; i<countryCount;i++){
        try {
            // Call getCountry with country JSON object to parse the country 
            country = getCountry((JSONObject)jCountries.get(i));
            countryList.add(country);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return countryList;
}

// Parsing the Country JSON object 
private HashMap<String, Object> getCountry(JSONObject jCountry){

    HashMap<String, Object> country = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    String flag="";


    } catch (JSONException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return country;
   }
  }
```

Here is my `XML` files:one for `ListView` and other is for `ListView` items:

```
**activity_main.xml**
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >    


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_countries"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
     android:background="@drawable/gradient_drawable"
         android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5" />


</RelativeLayout>

**lv_layout.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_country"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  

        android:textSize="20dp"   
        android:textStyle="bold" /> 

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/iv_flag"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"

       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/str_iv_flag" />


      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right_arrow"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow2"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

   <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_country_details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_flag"

        android:layout_below="@id/tv_country"  /> 

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried out  **"[How to set onClickListener for separate parts of custom listView item? [Android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768939/how-to-set-onclicklistener-for-separate-parts-of-custom-listview-item-android)"** post 
    but it does not solved my problem because it does take me a new activity means nothing happened and also i am not getting any error.so please help me out on this issue.

Comment: post your adapter class

Comment: You can simply call `OnItemClickListener` method for `ListView`.

Comment: are you using custom listview...if yes please share adapter here and if not use custom listview with adapter and handle click in adapter..

Comment: see my edited post above. i have added my adapter class.

Comment: But in your custom adapter class where did you inflated your view?

Comment: sorry guys for late comment actually i am working on your suggestions but nothing helped me.please guys if u make addition or correction in my code posted above.also  i am not using any adapter class.Anyways thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Get the text of the clicked item from the listviewin the listener, and then take decision that which activity should be started on click ,taken from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959576/custom-listview-start-new-activity)

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
         // In the following line "v" refers to the View returned by the `getView()` method; meaning the clicked View.
         TextView txtName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewID);
         String name = txtName.getText().toString();
         switch(name)
         {
              case "nameOne":
                  Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, NameOneActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
                  break;

              case "nameTwo":
                   Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, NameTwoActivity.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   break;

              //And so on and so forth....
         }

    }
});
```

Comment: thank u for your help. but the above code work with custombaseadapter but in my code i am not using this class. so please see my code and tell what to do in this case and if its neccessary to use custom list adapter and if yes, then tell where to use it and its whole code. and sorry for bothering u.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your BaseAdpter class set onClickListener on each Item and then in onCLick start the activity you want like this:

```
image1.setOnClickListener(this);
image2.setOnClickListener(this);
textview.ssetOnClickListener(this);
```

then

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
switch(view.getId()){
case image1.getId():
mActivity.startAcivity(new Intent(mActivity,ActivityToStart.class));
break;
case image2.getId():
mActivity.startAcivity(new Intent(mActivity,ActivityToStart.class));
break;
.....and so on
}
}
```

Comment: sorry but it didn't help me

Comment: Did you add this to the viewholder class or inside getView of BaseAdapter?

Comment: sorry but as in my code posted above i have no adapter class so please suggest a code of adapter class  or type(base or custom) which is relevent to my  posted code.I just tried out a link given in my code not actually implemented because it give me too much errors in my project.

Comment: I have created a demo hope this will help.

https://github.com/ankitkhare0804/demobaseadapter

Comment: thank u for the effort ,i'll get back to u after applying your demo.

Comment: hi,i implemented your demo but i am confused on where to set onclicklistner and onclick method. wheather in viewholder class or mainactivity class.i tried in both classes but getting errors.

Comment: inside ViewHolder class constructor. Implement the listener to the demoadapter class and in onClick use the above code .