# How to set onClickListener for custom ListView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

I have created a custom ListView, where the layout is definited in two XML, one which contain the definition of the ListView in a layout

For example **activity_main.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The other part of the XML is in another file, for example **custom_list.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/photoList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/takePhoto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/camera"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my activity i have declared actvivity_main.xml as main layout:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{    
    private List<CustomRow> imageList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cmp_details); 

        /* Initialization structures, variable, ecc */
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.imageList);
        adapter = new CustomList(this, imageList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /* Add element list in ListView */
    private void addList(int idC){
        CustomRow cr = new CustomRow();
        cr.setId(idC);
        cr.setTitle("xxx "+ (idC+1));
        cr.setThumbnailUrl(R.drawable.no_image);
        imageList.add(cr);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void takePhoto(){
     //Do something   
    }
}
```

**Custom List.java**

```
public class CustomList extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<CustomRow> ListItem;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomList(Activity activity, List<CustomRow> listPhotoItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.ListItem = listPhotoItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ListItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return ListItem.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        ImageView thumbNail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        CustomRow m = ListItem.get(position);
        thumbNail.setImageResource(m.getThumbnailUrl());
        title.setTag(m.getId());
        title.setText(m.getTitle());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Now I have to implement the OnClickListener of takePhoto, how I can do this ?
How I can bind onClickListener from the activity ?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768939/how-to-set-onclicklistener-for-separate-parts-of-custom-listview-item-android) solution but not work...

Comment: set click listener in getView method as anonymous.

Comment: Could you make me one example with code / pseudo ? I tell you this because I tried some solution but nothing work...

Comment: where is  takePhoto

Comment: takePhoto is a fuction that start the camera, this is definited in MainActivity. I have not posted the code because the content is not decisive in order to solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use  setonitemclicklistener

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
 imageList.get(position); // here you will get the clicked item from 
    //your imagelist and you can check by getting a title  by using this

    String title= imageList.get(position).getTitle();
    if(title.equals("you title to match")){
    //do your action or you can get a particular position and click there
    }
           } 
        });
```

Comment: I have only another question: this code allow to me to bind the onClickListener of the LISTVIEW... How I can bind the onClickListener of the ImageView in the ListView ??

Comment: If you have another question then ask it separately and why you uncheck my answer as accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

This is the final solution, I have solve my problem with this code:

```
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            View convertView = v;

            final ImageView photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.takePhoto);
            photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(CmpDetails.this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have commeted an error, infact if you read my previous reply you can see that is your the correct solution :)

Answer (score 1):

```
tv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
 list.get(position); 

    String str= list.get(position).getTitle();
       if(str.equals("")){
           //put your code here
  }
       } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do your code on click event
        }
    });


    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

Comment: try this one http://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial, but click evnet as I have already post in answer.

Comment: I see your edit but I can't declare onClickListener in the custom_list class, I need to declare in the mainActivity ...

Comment: You don't want to do something your self. hundreds of examples available on stackoverflow, androidhive,journaldev etc.

Comment: I will answer no further because I will not unleash flame ... If i'm here on StackOverflow it's because I have already tried many solutions, I certainly expect to have everything ready like most people. Anyway I tried various solutions and should not be, this could lead to the presumption that my case is different, in fact I posted the code